# ExtJS - ComboBox width in EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

I have set up an EditorGridPanel with ComboBox's and it's working well. The only issue I'm having is that the width of the ComboBox seems to only expand to the width of the grid column, and not the content of the ComboBox itself.

**Is there a way around this?**

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: ComboBox in EditorGridPanel]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the

> listWidth : Number

config option

You could calculate the length of the largest content element and then set the listWidth in the 'expand' event of the combo

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> listWidth does'nt exist in extjs 4.

Add below to combobox config:

```
matchFieldWidth: false,
listConfig: {
    width: 200
},
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use RowEditor to managed multi forms editor !
see sencha's samples ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I can't find anything in the docs about "muilti forms".

Comment: If you have a grid panel , you can using plugins : CellEditing or Rowediting. With CellEditing, you can having a grid with multi form on columns ! For exemple : One col no editable, one columns textfield editable, one with combobox ... !

You have just to add xtype on field config :
Example :



`columns : [  {  
     header : 'BudgetType',
    field : {
      
      xtype : 'combobox',
    
    
     }
   }
   , {  
   
     id : 'Descriptiongridid',
      flex : 2,
     field : {
      
      xtype : 'textfield',`